# Difference between using document and element for on event trigger

Tags: jquery

Given these two jquery on event triggers

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-trigger='colorbox']",function(e){

$("a[data-trigger='colorbox']").on("click",function(e){
```

I had to click on the anchor tag twice before the colorbox is triggered when I used the first one. For subsequent clicks, it doesnt require a second click to trigger. But for the second one, the colorbox is triggered on the very first click. Is there any difference between the two?

my content for the function is as below

```
e.preventDefault();
var currentTarget = $(e.currentTarget);
currentTarget.colorbox({inline : true, href : currentTarget.data("href")});
```

Comment: The first is the event delegation technique and the 2nd is the direct binding.

Comment: The two different ways should not have caused you to need to click twice in one of them, they are identical (in terms of functionality) if both elements exist on the page at dom ready.

Comment: could you post the content of the click function?

Comment: I would suggest this video here:
http://training.bocoup.com/screencasts/more-efficient-event-handlers/
Definitely will help you grasp this concept fully.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-trigger='colorbox']",function(e){
```

This binds a click event to the document and all child elements within it. This click event then checks if the clicked element matches the filter `a[data-trigger='colorbox']`

the later:

```
$("a[data-trigger='colorbox']").on("click",function(e){
```

binds the click event to the `a[data-trigger='colorbox']` directly.

Now if your element is dynamic you would want to use the first one. As this means you don't have to keep rebinding your click event. If your element is static then you want to use the later as it's more efficient.

A third way (or a more efficientway to do the first option) is to bind this to a *parent* element that is static as opposed to the `document` and then filter on the element being clicked, i.e.

```
$(parent).on("click", "a[data-trigger='colorbox']",function(e){
```

this is more efficent because it does not need to capture click events on the entire document

Comment: oh nice. Why doesnt the second one applies to a dynamic element?

Comment: the second one is directly bound to your element, so if the element is removed and then re-added (i.e. loaded dynamically) you lose the binding. The other works in this scenario because it is bound to a static element and it's just testing for your dynamic selector

Answer (score 1):

The 1st method captures an event that has bubbled up from the element through its parents until the document. This method is referred to as **delegated event handling**

The second one: captures the event directly on the element.

### What is going on in the background:

**Document structure**:

- document

  - grand parent

    - parent

      - element
    - parent2
  - ...

**Event**: The user clicks on **element**

**Outcome:**

1. All click listeners of **element** are executed * (**Your 2nd case**)
2. The event starts to bubble
3. All click listeners of **parent** are executed *
4. All click listeners of **grand parent** are executed *
5. All click listeners of **document** are executed * (**Your 1st case**)

***The listeners** get the event object, and have the possibility to cancel the bubbling by calling:

- `event.stopPropagation()`: Doesn't let the event propagate to parents, but executes all listeners on current level.
- `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`: Doesn't let the event propagate to parents and no other listeners will be invoked on the same level either

JQuery can handle click events of **element** in a listener that is bound to the document because on every layer you can check the click event object for information:

- The currently handling event `event.currentTarget`
- The element that was originally clicked `event.target`

More at **[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)**

### Back to your situation

#### Case 2

Is pretty straightforward:

1. the element is clicked
2. its handler is executed

If the element is dynamically added / removed etc. You have to take care of its handlers (assign / deassign etc.)

#### Case 1

The element is clicked:

1. The event bubbles up until the document
2. The handler on document is called
3. The handler verifies that the event is from a click that was made on your element

You should opt for this solution if your element is dynamically added/removed and you don't want to manage click handlers on it. Nevertheless you shouldn't assign it on document, since then the basic listener will be called for **every** click on the page, jQuery will check if the `target` was the element you are interested in and call the handler specified by you if it is the case. All in all, this can decrease performance if overused.

Knowing all this should help you find out what is the behavioral difference in your situation.